# NSFecthedResultsController and NSArray EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a strange crash on setting an NSArray from the fetchedObjects in NSFetchedResultsController as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Both visibleShotsArray and fetchedResultsController are not nil and have objects, so I cannot understand why the EXC_BAD_ADRESS is happening.

[image]

Fabric logs don't help a lot because the obj_msgSend usually happens when a deallocated object is called, and that's not my case I think.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is the status of `self.visibleShotsArray` before the Bad access line? Is it already filled with 300 object / an empty array / nil ? Moreover,  self.visibleShotsArray is declared as NSArray property or NSMutableArray?

Comment: self.visibleShotsArray is an NSArray and before the crash has 300 objects

Comment: Ok, did you try to make the assignment differently? like self.visibleShotsArray = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObject copy]

Comment: No I don't try it because the crash happens only once every multiple executions and I'm trying to understand it. Now I have Xcode stopped at this line with the crash and If I do a po self.visibleShotsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:@[@1,@2]] the array is set ok, so it's seems to be a problem with the fetchedResultsController. Thanks Luca

Comment: Is fetchedResultsController declared with a strong reference like `@property (nonatomic, strong)  NSFecthedResultsController* fetchedResultsController;` ? I mean, maybe you lose the reference and this can cause the bad access. In case, you can store the result once fetchedResultsController finishes

Comment: Both fetchedResultsController and visibleShotsArray are nonatomic, strong references. And I can print out the fecthedResultsController.fetchedObjects in the console when the crash happens. I found some similar issue in the Apple forums, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7628 but not use if it's my case.

Comment: Intersting, I've just read the thread to the link you posted. What if you just assign the self.visibleShotsArray to the fetchedObjects like `self.visibleShotsArray = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]`, so just keeping the pointer to the same array? Would mess up your app logic?

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion, seems to work right now, but before was so difficult to reproduce it...Thanks man.

Comment: I know is not a concrete solution, it's more a workaround that could fit your particular needs, anyway, glad to help you ;)

Comment: I'm distributing a beta testers version so I can have feedback soon. Thanks a lot Luca !